# Showing/hiding checkbox based on another checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Looking to have it so that when the first checkbox is selected (`geographic_checkbox`), a further 2 checkboxes are displayed (`regions,cities &towns_checkbox` and `ringfencing_checkbox`), but for some reason my code is not working.

```js
$('#geographic_checkbox').on('click', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#geographic_suboptions').removeClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('#geographic_suboptions').addClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="targeting">
  <h1>Targeting</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="geographic" value="0.00" id="geographic_checkbox" onclick="GeographicFunction()">Geographic<br>
      <p id="geographic_text" style="display:none">+£0.08 CPC</p>
      <div id="geographic_suboptions" class="hidden">
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox" name="regions,cities&towns" value="0.08" id="regions,cities&towns_checkbox" onclick="RegionsFunction()">Regions, Cities & Towns<br></li>
          <p id="regions,cities&towns_text" style="display:none">+£0.08 CPC</p>
          <li><input type="checkbox" name="ringfencing" value="0.09" id="ringfencing_checkbox" onclick="RingfencingFunction()">Ring-Fencing<br></li>
          <p id="ringfencing_text" style="display:none">+£0.08 CPC</p>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your current code seems to be working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/76ujpd2v/

Comment: Your code is already working.

Comment: just tried and it doesn't seem to work on safari or chrome for me

Comment: Check the console in dev tools for errors. Also ensure that the snippet above matches your code *exactly*.

Comment: @bboooooyintheuk Can you please `upvote` usefull answer ? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually for such a feature you not really need `javascript` since `css` provide the `:checked` selector:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

ul input:checked ~ #geographic_suboptions {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="targeting">
  <h1>Targeting</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="geographic" value="0.00" id="geographic_checkbox">Geographic<br>
      <p id="geographic_text" style="display:none">+£0.08 CPC</p>
      <div id="geographic_suboptions" class="hidden">
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox" name="regions,cities&towns" value="0.08" id="regions,cities&towns_checkbox">Regions, Cities & Towns<br></li>
          <p id="regions,cities&towns_text" style="display:none">+£0.08 CPC</p>
          <li><input type="checkbox" name="ringfencing" value="0.09" id="ringfencing_checkbox">Ring-Fencing<br></li>
          <p id="ringfencing_text" style="display:none">+£0.08 CPC</p>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```